# Get a drive out of the read only mode

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, mount, repair

I got a problem with my new m2 ssd KINGSTON SA2000M8250G.

I just installed it 2 weeks ago. Now out of nothing it stopped booting with the following output.

```
Failed to flush random seed file: 5712F72E
Error loading \EFI\Pop_OS-c6e0a2ef-5953-402b-ad6d-2a95da3956d7\vmlinuz.efi: Not Found.
```

So i tried around checked my BIOS if secure boot was enabled just to make sure and it wasn't ...

So i got a Ubuntu Live USB and played around and mybe i messed it up even more... (I am not sure)

So now my drive is in **Read only Mode**
And i really need some help :).
The Drive does not contain important data! So losing data would be fine if it is usable again.

Some Info:

1. The dirve is an Internal one.
2. The dirve contains a system

I used smartctl to get some information about the drive.

```
sudo smartctl -x -q noserial /dev/nvme0
```

The output:

```
smartctl 7.1 2019-12-30 r5022 [x86_64-linux-5.4.0-42-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-19, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Number:                       KINGSTON SA2000M8250G
Firmware Version:                   S5Z42105
PCI Vendor/Subsystem ID:            0x2646
IEEE OUI Identifier:                0x0026b7
Controller ID:                      1
Number of Namespaces:               1
Namespace 1 Size/Capacity:          250,059,350,016 [250 GB]
Namespace 1 Utilization:            141,657,182,208 [141 GB]
Namespace 1 Formatted LBA Size:     512
Namespace 1 IEEE EUI-64:            0026b7 683dc07055
Local Time is:                      Thu Dec  3 20:08:05 2020 UTC
Firmware Updates (0x14):            2 Slots, no Reset required
Optional Admin Commands (0x0017):   Security Format Frmw_DL Self_Test
Optional NVM Commands (0x005f):     Comp Wr_Unc DS_Mngmt Wr_Zero Sav/Sel_Feat Timestmp
Maximum Data Transfer Size:         32 Pages
Warning  Comp. Temp. Threshold:     75 Celsius
Critical Comp. Temp. Threshold:     80 Celsius

Supported Power States
St Op     Max   Active     Idle   RL RT WL WT  Ent_Lat  Ex_Lat
 0 +     9.00W       -        -    0  0  0  0        0       0
 1 +     4.60W       -        -    1  1  1  1        0       0
 2 +     3.80W       -        -    2  2  2  2        0       0
 3 -   0.0450W       -        -    3  3  3  3     2000    2000
 4 -   0.0040W       -        -    4  4  4  4    15000   15000

Supported LBA Sizes (NSID 0x1)
Id Fmt  Data  Metadt  Rel_Perf
 0 +     512       0         0

=== START OF SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: FAILED!
- media has been placed in read only mode

SMART/Health Information (NVMe Log 0x02)
Critical Warning:                   0x08
Temperature:                        25 Celsius
Available Spare:                    100%
Available Spare Threshold:          10%
Percentage Used:                    0%
Data Units Read:                    486,334 [249 GB]
Data Units Written:                 476,639 [244 GB]
Host Read Commands:                 2,838,965
Host Write Commands:                3,809,355
Controller Busy Time:               45
Power Cycles:                       100
Power On Hours:                     25
Unsafe Shutdowns:                   25
Media and Data Integrity Errors:    17,200,105
Error Information Log Entries:      0
Warning  Comp. Temperature Time:    0
Critical Comp. Temperature Time:    0

Error Information (NVMe Log 0x01, max 256 entries)
No Errors Logged
```

I tried the following. To get file system and mount point information.

```
lsblk -f | grep -v loop
```

The output:

```
NAME        FSTYPE      FSVER            LABEL              UUID                                 FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINT
sda                                                                                                             
├─sda1      vfat        FAT32                               1201-2A0D                                           
├─sda2                                                                                                          
└─sda3      ntfs                                            789408C894088AB8                                    
sdb         iso9660     Joliet Extension Ubuntu 20.10 amd64 2020-10-22-14-30-30-00                              
├─sdb1      iso9660     Joliet Extension Ubuntu 20.10 amd64 2020-10-22-14-30-30-00                     0   100% /cdrom
├─sdb2      vfat        FAT12            ESP                F366-AE33                                           
├─sdb3                                                                                                          
└─sdb4      ext4        1.0              writable           dff793be-6f59-425e-b89a-4e175c2b66d7   24.8G     0% /var/crash
nvme0n1                                                                                                         
├─nvme0n1p1 vfat        FAT32                               4632-74A2                                           
├─nvme0n1p2 vfat        FAT32                               4632-7222                                           
├─nvme0n1p3 crypto_LUKS 2                                   8053e722-94b5-4966-af53-c3d656019acd                
└─nvme0n1p4 swap        1                                   7b732792-e513-4074-b343-f17ab7b652f7
```

But there was no output from the commands above.

**How to get it out of the Read only Mode xD**

Thx for helping me out.

Comment: Simply get it replaced on warranty if you can. I wouldn't trust a drive that fails in 2 weeks.

Comment: but the question is is it really a hardware failure? Or did the software mess up the partitioning or what ever?

Comment: Partitioning is just writing data. The disk doesn't know what a partition is. Anyway, hardware or firmware failure, if it really stops booting out of nowhere and you can't associate it with something you did, it shouldn't be trusted.

Comment: thx i am going to refund it :)

Comment: Additionally refusing to accept new data ("media has been placed in read only mode") is what the SSD does to prevent further damage to existing data. It knows there's something wrong and does its best so you can copy whatever you can still read from the drive without making the situation worse.

Comment: In my case, I *did* manage to get the data off, and I'm being offered a refund, but I can't send it back with sensitive data still on there. I now *want* catastrophic data loss, without physically damaging the drive (which might lead to no refund). Is there any way to get around the read only mode?

Comment: @Trembly I dont think there is a way to get it out but i am not sure. But it might be possible to erase/format all data on the drive if i remember correctly.

Comment: "Critical Warning:                   0x08" - the drive itself witched to read only, no amount of partitioning or formatting etc. will solve this, as the firmware will simply not honor commands that write to the drive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This here

```
Media and Data Integrity Errors:    17,200,105
```

means it's really really broken. Which is why it put itself into read-only mode.

Get it replaced.

Answer (score 1):

Although your smartctl looks different than the ones from my SSDs your smartmontools log information tells you all:

```
=== START OF SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: **FAILED!**
- media has been placed in **read** only mode

SMART/Health Information (NVMe Log 0x02)
Critical Warning:                   0x08
Temperature:                        25 Celsius
Available Spare:                    100%
Available Spare Threshold:          10%
Percentage Used:                    0%
Data Units Read:                    486,334 [249 GB]
Data Units Written:                 476,639 [244 GB]
Host Read Commands:                 2,838,965
Host Write Commands:                3,809,355
Controller Busy Time:               45
Power Cycles:                       100
Power On Hours:                     25
**Unsafe Shutdowns:                   25**
**Media and Data Integrity Errors:    17,200,105**
```

This happened independant of what you did on higher levels with the drive, for instance on file system level. There is a certain probability though of your behaviour causing this erroneous behaviour: The drive reports unsafe shutdowns.

Please monitor this attribute when using your next drive. Avoid irregular hard shut downs.

As for the comments, I totally agree with what Kamil M. said.

Comment: yeahr but ther was only one unsafe shutdown as of what i know. Could it also be just an corrupt unit? I mean it was basically new and i had an other one running for 2 years before the new one with hunderts of unsafe shutdowns ?

Comment: This drive reports 25, you say 1, now there is another one with x*100 unsafe shutdowns? I can't follow you.

Comment: Okay xD. So i had an other m2 ssd bevore this Kingston one. It was working just fine even though i had somm power losses and it was shuting down unsafly very often over the period of two years :). And the old one did not have any trouble or Media and Data Integrity Errors. So i am thinking after two weeks of this kingston it might just be a defect one xD